# Add javascript code in payment.phtml in the Magento

Tags: magento, action

I have the following layout xml

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="gate/paycheckout" name="payair.gate.paycheckout" before="-" template="gate/checkout.phtml"/>
    <block type="gate/paymentjs" name="payair.gate.paymentjs" />
</reference>
```

I have a block by which i am calling the javascript on the payment.phtml and its working but i want to call the Magento addJs action method to add the javascript dynamically on the payment.phtml page not by calling the block. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should add the script to head:

layout xml file:

```
<layout>
  <name_of_the_handle>
    <reference name="head">
      <action method="addJs"><script>gate/payment.js</script></action>
    </reference>
  </name_of_the_handle>
  ...
</layout>
```

payment.js file should in this case be located in js/gate/payment.js

Comment: i do not want to add in the js in the head specially. Want to add only in the payment.phtml..Thanks

Comment: If you search for addJs function in Magento source code you will see that this function only exists in Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head so you won't be able to use it in other modules unless you implement something like that yourself in your own block. You should just use the above code and replace name_of_the_handle with handle name that exists only when rendering payment.phtml file.

Comment: Then what will be reference name? Can you suggest me? I am trying like this...<layout>
  <checkout_onepage_index>
    <reference name="content">
      <action method="addJs"><script>gate/payment.js</script></action>
    </reference>
  </name_of_the_handle>
  ...
</layout>

Comment: reference name="head". name attribute is the name of block on which a function should be called. method attribute value in action element is actualy the name of class function that should be called. So since addJs function only exists in Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head block you should reference that block.